# Google Sheets Script - Looping through all sheets, and adding all values of a certain column into array to then count unique values

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to loop through all sheets (I was 57) and get all the elements from the first column,and add them into an array to then, that I can later access with ALL the ids from ALL the sheets.The problem with my code is that the ids array is not loading correctly. When I print ids.length it equals 0. So I'm guessing something is wrong on my forEach loop where it won't push the values into the array.

```
function countLinesPerCharacter() {
  let app = SpreadsheetApp;
  let spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  let allSheets = spreadsheet.getSheets()
  
  let targetSheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("lines");
  
  let ids = []
  let y = 2
  //goes thrrough each sheet 
  allSheets.forEach(function(sheet){
    sheet.activate() 
    //goes through the rows 
    //row col
    
    let lastRowNumber = spreadsheet.getLastRow();
    for(let i = 0; i < lastRowNumber.length; i++) {
      let  questionID = spreadsheet.getRange(i, 1).getValue();
      ids.push(questionID) // IT WON'T LOAD THE questionID into ids ----
      y++
     }
  })
  
  targetSheet.getRange(1, 5).setValue(ids.length); //ids.length = 0
  targetSheet.getRange(1, 1).setValue("Done going through each sheet");
  
}
```

Comment: Can I ask you about the current issue of your script?

Comment: The ids array is empty. Somehow it's not pushing correctly.

Comment: Add a [mcve] (the current code isn't complete an doesn't include sample input data and the corresponding expected result)

Comment: Thank you for replying. The start number of `getRange` is `1`. But it seems that in your script, `0` is the start number. And also, at `spreadsheet.getRange(i, 1).getValue()`, I think that in your script, the 1st tab is always used as `spreadsheet`. How about these? By the way, what is `let y = 3`?

Comment: Yes I saw that and changed it to 'for(var i = 2; i < lastRowNumber.length; i++) {' but nothing changes.

Answer (score 1):

### Issues:

> for(let i = 0; i < lastRowNumber.length; i++) {

- `lastRowNumber` is of type `Number` and doesn't have a `.length` property.`lastRowNumber.length` is `undefined` and as `i` is not less than `undefined`, the loop never starts.

> spreadsheet.getLastRow()

- This  only gets the first sheet's last row. Last row of the current sheet should be retrieved.

> spreadsheet.getRange(i, 1)

- Spreadsheet doesn't have a `.getRange( number, number)` method. Only sheet class does.

### Modified script:

**Old script:**

```js
function countLinesPerCharacter() {
  const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const allSheets = spreadsheet.getSheets();
  const targetSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('lines');
  const ids = [];
  //goes thrrough each sheet
  allSheets.forEach(function(sheet) {
//sheet.activate();
//goes through the rows
//row col

const lastRowNumber = sheet.getLastRow();//modified getlastRow from sheet 
for (let i = 1; i <= lastRowNumber; i++) {//modified=> length removed; "<"=>"<=";i=0=>i=1
  const questionID = sheet.getRange(i, 1).getValue();//getRange from sheet 
  ids.push(questionID); 
}
  });

  targetSheet.getRange(1, 5).setValue(ids.length); //ids.length = 0
  targetSheet.getRange(1, 1).setValue('Done going through each sheet');
}
```

**Optimized script:**

```
function countLinesPerCharacter2() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName('lines');
  const ids = ss
    .getSheets()
    .map(sheet => sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow()).getValues())
    .flat(2);
  targetSheet.getRange(1, 5).setValue(ids.length);
}
```

### To Read:

- [Best Practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide_common_tasks#OptimizeScripts)
- [Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.  I simplified some of your expressions.  Couple notes:

1. Don't forget your semicolons.  Good use of `let` throughout.
2. Remember that `allSheets` is every sheet, including `targetSheet`.

```
function myFunction() {
 let allSheets   = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets();
 let targetSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("lines");
 
 let ids = [];
 //goes thrrough each sheet 
 allSheets.forEach(function(sheet){
   sheet.activate();
   //goes through the rows 
   //row col
   
   let rows = sheet.getRange("A:A").getValues();  // handy way to select the whole first column
   rows = rows.filter(row => row[0] !== ""); // remove blank values based on the first column (you may want to remove this)
   rows.forEach(row => ids.push(row));
 });
// console.log(ids);      // optional diagnostic
 
 targetSheet.getRange(1, 5).setValue(ids.length);
 targetSheet.getRange(1, 1).setValue("Done going through each sheet");
}
```

Comment: That helped but gets stuck on the first sheet. I did a for loop to print the array, and only displays the id's from the first sheet. 
 
`let x = 2 //row i want to start in 
  for(let i = 2; i < ids.length; i++) {
     targetSheet.getRange(x, 2).setValue(ids[i]);
     //targetSheet.getRange(x, 4).setValue("debugging");
     x++
  }`

Comment: Remember that this will grab only non-blank cells in Column A of every sheet. Do you have any formula outputs or other weird cells?

Uncomment the `console.log` and check its output. I made a spreadsheet with three tabs and it collected everything it was supposed to and nothing it didn't.